# Using MOUSE_EVENTS instead of TOUCH

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, events, air

Are Mouse Events Equivalent to the Touch Events in Adobe AIR for Android 
I mean can i use use CLICK instead of TAP .
MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP for SWIPE.
I am building an Android App in Flash(cs6) . Is it necessary to use TOUCH events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No is not necessary, if you need only to track 1 "input/finger" at time you can use MouseEvents.

TouchEvents have been created to handle multiple "input" at the same time.